# Python Multiprocessing read and write to large file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, multiprocessing, chunks

I have a large file of 120GB consisting of strings line by line. I would like to loop the file line by line replacing all the German characters ß with characters s. I have a working code, but it is very slow, and in the future, I should be replacing more German characters. So I have been trying to cut the file in 6 pieces (for my 6-core CPU ) and incorporate multicore processing to speed the code up, but with no luck.

As lines are not ordered, I do not care where the lines in the new file will end up. Can somebody please help me?

My working slow code:

```
import re

with open('C:\Projects\orders.txt', 'r') as f, open('C:\Projects\orders_new.txt', 'w') as nf: 
        for l in f:
                l = re.sub("ß", "s", l)
                nf.write(l)
```

Comment: You cannot intermingle writes to a single file.  Remember, the files are buffered, and each process has its own buffer, which doesn't not necessarily end on a line boundary.  You can write to 6 different files, then combine them when you're done.  You don't have to do this line-by-line.  You can do one huge `read`.  Wouldn't this task be better done from a command line, using something like `sed`?

Comment: And you don't need `re.sub`.  A simple `l.replace` will do.  And isn't "ß" usually replaced by "ss"?

Comment: Hi, tnx for the comments. I am using `re.sub` because I will need a regex match in the future to match for example if ß is in the first line, and need to replace it with "s".

@TimRoberts The problem with `read` is that the file is too big for my memory. I only have 8GB. And as `for line in f:` is very efficient with memory usage, I was hoping to slice the file in 6 parts and then have 6 writes and then concatenate that to 1 file, but I just don't know where to start :/

Comment: You can use `f.seek` to position the file before beginning.  Take the length of the file divided by 6, and give each subprocess a starting location and a length.

Comment: Tnx for the idea, will try using `f.seek`

Comment: It is not slow because you are running it on one CPU core, it is slow because writing 120GB to disk is slow. Running it in multiple cores does not help. If you can split that file into multiple files and put them on different disks, maybe that would help.

Comment: @zvone currently, when reading and writing with one core, in my activity log I see only about 5-10% of disk usage. The file is on a fast SSD disk.

Comment: And CPU is at 100%? I doubt that, although, you should not use regex when you want speed and especially when you just want something as simple as this.

Comment: Yep, one core is 100% CPU. I am using regex because, in the future, I will need to find, for example, only ß when it is at the beginning of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a multiprocessing solution to be more performant than the equivalent single-processing one, the worker function must be sufficiently CPU-intensive such that running the function in parallel saves enough time to compensate for the additional overhead that multiprocessing incurs.

To make the worker function sufficiently CPU-intensive, I would batch up the lines to be translated into chunks so that each invocation of the worker function involves more CPU. You can play around with the `CHUNK_SIZE` value (read the comments that precedes its definition). If you have sufficient memory, the larger the better.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_chunks():
    # If you have N processors,
    # then we need memory to hold 2 * (N - 1) chunks (one processor
    # is reserved for the main process).
    # The size of a chunk is CHUNK_SIZE * average-line-length.
    # If the average line length were 100, then a chunk would require
    # approximately 1_000_000 bytes of memory.
    # So if you had, for example, a 16MB machine with 8 processors,
    # you would have more
    # than enough memory for this CHUNK_SIZE.
    CHUNK_SIZE = 1_000

    with open('C:\Projects\orders.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        chunk = []
        while True:
            line = f.readline()
            if line == '': # end of file
                break
            chunk.append(line)
            if len(chunk) == CHUNK_SIZE:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []
        if chunk:
            yield chunk

def worker(chunk):
    # This function must be sufficiently CPU-intensive
    # to justify multiprocessing.
    for idx in range(len(chunk)):
        chunk[idx] = chunk[idx].replace("ß", "s")
    return chunk

def main():
    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1) as pool, \
    open('C:\Projects\orders_new.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as nf:
        for chunk in pool.imap_unordered(worker, get_chunks()):
            nf.write(''.join(chunk))
            """
            Or to be more memory efficient, but slower:
            for line in chunk:
                nf.write(chunk)
            """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately, for now, this code is way out of my league with classes and everything. I will study it for a few days and try it out. Thanks.

Comment: You just need to look at the source from `def get_chunks()` to the end.

Comment: Yep, the only part I understand for now is `def get_chunks():` and `def worker(chunk):` but I will try to make sense of everything. So, currently, if I remove the classes, is there a chance I could get memory overflow?

Comment: You shouldn't be so fast to accept the solution because I am fairly certain you will find that a single process solution that you already have (but using the `replace` string method) is going to be significantly faster. There is just too much overhead in moving data from one process to another. I was going to let you discover this for yourself. But the approach would be sound if the processing of each line were significantly more CPU-intensive to justify that overhead.

Comment: As far as memory overflow, it's a question of whether `worker` can keep up with the generating and moving of the data. In this case it probably can and a "standard" `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` would be sufficient. But, in the case where multiprocessing would be advantageous, i.e. where the `worker` function tasks significant time, then you very well could have memory issues.

Comment: Now it may be (I haven't looked at the implementation closely) that with methods `imap` and `imap_unordered` that the pool only iterates the past iterable when a pool process becomes idle and is looking for the next task to process. If that is the case (and I will try to research this), then there is not much point in using my special pool class. However, if tasks are being submitted with calls to `apply_async`, then you would definitely need to worry about memory utilization going up if you are calling this method in a loop instead of using `imap_unordered`.

Comment: I ran a benchmark looking at memory utilization with `imap_unordered` and it appears that the passed iterable is only iterated by the pool as processes become idle and looking for new work to perform. So the memory would not continue to grow just because the iterable can be iterated faster than a process can process the work. However, if you are using `apply_async` instead memory utilization definitely starts to rise if the worker function cannot process a task as fast as a new task is generated.  I will updated the answer and remove the specialized class.

Comment: Well, @Booboo, thank you so much for the explanation. I understand what is going on in the script with your new edit. 

One more question, I was thinking of chunking the file to the identical `(multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1)` parts. What do you think, in theory, is what is more efficient, having every CPU core reading one and writing to the new.txt_chunk1 and then concatenating all the chunks in one file? Or doing this with a fixed chunk size by lines?

Comment: Unless you have a solid state drive then writing multiple files concurrently will not be more performant. In fact, it could hurt disk performance because the disk head can potentially be moving more than it otherwise would be. And how can you have multiple processes reading separate chunks from the same file in parallel? If it were a binary file each process could seek to a specific offset and read up until another offset. But here we are dealing with an encoded text file (utf-8?) where characters are encoded in a varying number of bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested the code, and it is going 3-4 times faster than using one CPU. I will play with chunk_size variable now.

@Booboo `if line == '': # end of file` is this checking if the line is empty? What will happen if I have an empty line in the file which is not the end of the file?

Comment: Yes, but:. When you call method `readline` on a file it is guranteed to come back with a non-empty string, even if it is just  the single character '\n', until you hit an end of file condition in which case it returns an empty string. So this is testing for end of file as can also be determined by (1)  It breaking out of the `while` loop and testing to see if there is a final, partial chunk to be sent as the last one or (2) By reading the [Python manual description for `readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readline#io.TextIOBase.readline).

Comment: That is, if a line is "empty", it still has a newline character and that will be returned.